# Как в ComboBox внести массив символов и потом обращаться к ним?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Как в ComboBox внести массив символов `{'+','-','/','*'}` и потом обращаться к ним? Пробовал так:

```
char[] symbols = char[]{'+','-','/','*'}
comboBox.AddRange(symbols);
```

Выдавало ошибку.

Comment: Если вы используете WPF, то я бы советовал для этого использовать также MVVM. Но если вы таки идете по трудному пути, то, если мне память не изменяет, можно писать `comboBox.ItemsSource = new []{'+','-','/','*'};`

Comment: Да! Спасибо, а как мне обратится к нужному мне элементу? Например мне нужно взять от туда умножение

Comment: Если вам надо получить именно умножение, то проще не обращаться к комбобоксу, а сразу использовать `'*'`. Если вам надо использовать то, что юзер выбрал, там у комбообкса есть что то типа `comboBox.SelectedValue`

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!